# HashMap and Pojo

Tags: java

```
Person{    
 private String name;    
 private Long id;    
 setter & getter    
}
```

`HashMap hashKey = new HashMap();`

into that  `HashMap` how put
Pojo properties and how to get them

and can any give me the help

Comment: Where's the effort on your part?

Comment: You're looking for the "The Reflection API"... probably.

Comment: @mschonaker I am really doubted about your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy

```
    Person person=new Person(); // create instance 
    person.setName("name"); //set values
    person.setId("id");

    HashMap<String,Person> hashKey = new HashMap<String,Person>();
    hashKey.put("key",person); //add person instance to Map with key
```

values in `Map` is `Person` type, only thing you have to make sure you are putting person instance to `Map` with a relevant key.

When you want to retrieve data from this `Map`, you can do in following way.

```
  Person person=hashKey.get("key") // retuning a person
```

Now you can get data contain in `person` using `getter` method.

```
 String name=person.getName();
 String id=person.getId();
```

Comment: You can't make use of diamond in the left side. you can use it in the rightside from JAVA SE 7

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is a generic class which is parameterized over type. You can very well make use of your pojo type in the type parameter with a Key as String type or any non-primitive type

```
//declaration and instantiation is done
HashMap<String,Person> personMap = new HashMap<String,Person>();
//Put the person instance in map with unique id to retrieve it back
String personId = "CASDF125"
Person person = new Person();
//set the properties in the Person instance and put it in the map
personMap.put(personId,person);
```

Hope this helps you understand!